# DRAM3 memory fetch time

Tags: fpga, dram

I am trying to understand how much time required in fpga time slots to fetch 128 bite value from DRAM3. I have a fpga board with 100 Mhz chip that talks with DRAM3 1600 Mhz. Thanks

Comment: Find the max data rate of the comm channel and then add overhead. Divide 128 bites by the max data rate + overhead.

Answer (score 1):

In general, DRAM access time depends on many factors:

- actual DRAM timings and frequency
- bus width
- whether operations access open or precharged rows and whether they are "pipelined"
- page and power policies of the DRAM controller
- internal details of the DRAM controller

If an order of magnitude estimation is okay, worst-case random access latency should be somewhere between 50 and 100 ns assuming no power saving modes are used.

ADDED: this also assumes the DRAM controller in the FPGA does not introduce its own latencies.